# "simply can not be" or "can not simply be"

Tags: adverbs, adverb-placement

I am looking into adverb order in sentences and came across the following one;

> There are things in this world which **simply cannot be** expressed in the form of words.

I think the above should better be like;

> There are things in this world which **cannot simply be** expressed in the form of words.

I wonder if the later is grammatically correct.

Google-ngram gives the following trends; [source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=simply%20can%20not%20be%2Ccan%20not%20simply%20be%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csimply%20can%20not%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20simply%20be%3B%2Cc0)
[image]

Are both the positions of the adverb ***simply*** fine, or only one of them is correct?

Answer (score -1):

We can put adverbs and adverb phrases at the front, in the middle or at the end of a clause. [[Resource from here]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position)

The front position of the clause is the first item in the clause:

> **Suddenly** I felt afraid.
>
> **Yesterday** detectives arrested a man and a woman in connection with the
>   murder.

The end position of the clause is the last item in the clause:

> Why do you always have to eat **so fast**?

The mid position is between the subject and the main verb:

> Apples **always** taste best when you pick them straight off the tree.

Where there is more than one verb, mid position means after the first auxiliary verb or after a modal verb:

> The government has **occasionally** been forced to change its mind. (after
>   the first auxiliary verb)
>
> You can **definitely** never predict what will happen. (after a modal
>   verb)
>
> We mightn’t **ever** have met. (after the modal verb and before the
>   auxiliary verb)

In questions, the mid position is between the subject and the main verb:

> Do you **ever** think about living there?

Adverbs usually come after the main verb be, except in emphatic clauses:

> She’s **always** late for everything.

When be is emphasized, the adverb comes before the verb:

> Why should I have gone to see Madonna? I **never** was a fan of hers.
>   (emphatic)

Comment: So, “can not simply be” is correct; but can't “simply can not be” be used to emphasize on "can" more than on "be"? I. O. W., can “simply can not be” never be correct-order?